# Python BeautifulSoup URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to ask is that how can I just get a part of URL in the  tag duing BeautifulSoup

Here is the href tag that return by BeautifulSoup:

```
<a href="https://www.goodsmile.info/zh/products/category/nendoroid_series/announced/2020" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.goodsmile.info/zh/products/category/nendoroid_series/announced/2020&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjT-_Gy4PzsAhWIyosBHd4ZAAkQFjBvegQIYhAC">
```

But I just want is:

```
https://www.goodsmile.info/zh/products/category/nendoroid_series/announced/2020
```

How can I do?

and here is some of my code:

```
for hit in soup.find_all(class_='g'):
    Hit_title = hit.find('h3')
    URL=hit.find(class_='yuRUbf').find('a', href=True).get('href')
```

What I need to modify?
Thanks

Comment: what data are you getting in the `hit` for that section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.attrs['href']` instead of `.get('href')`:

```
for hit in soup.find_all(class_='g'):
    Hit_title = hit.find('h3')
    URL=hit.find(class_='yuRUbf').find('a', href=True).attrs['href']
```